# not exists but not returning any results

Tags: sql-server, subquery, not-exists

There is 1 table.

| ParentServiceCategoryID | ServiceName | Entity TypeID mapped |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | landscape | 5 |
| 1 | landscape | 6 |
| 1 | landscape | 7 |
| 1 | Trimmings | 88 |
| 1 | Trimmings | 8 |
| 1 | Trimmings | 99 |

There are 3 services this company does: Landscape, Trimmings, and Shoveling.
Parent Service ID is called 'Outdoor Services'

I am trying to identify Outdoor Services that do not have 'Shoveling'. Example above would be captured. If the service had "shoveling' the same parent service category (Outdoor Services) then I do not want this captured.

Trying to do 'Not Exists' but returning no results

attempted code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
     (select * FROM table1 t2 
       where t1.ParentServiceCategoryID=t2.ParentServiceCategoryID
       AND t2.ServiceName='Shoveling'
     )
```

Comment: Your query works fine for your sample data provided: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FxD64PrI)

Comment: Maybe you need to check capitalization??

Answer (score 0):

using you're Query it's returning data except 'Shoveling'

```
declare @Table1 as table  
(
ParentServiceCategoryID int,    ServiceName varchar(8000),
EntityTypeIDmapped int)  
insert into @Table1
values  
(1, 'landscape',    5 ),  
(1, 'landscape',    6 ),  
(1, 'landscape',    7 ),  
(1, 'Trimmings',    88),  
(1, 'Trimmings',    8 ),  
(1, 'Trimmings',    99)  

SELECT * 
FROM @table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS  
     (select * FROM @table1 t2   
       where t1.ParentServiceCategoryID=t2.ParentServiceCategoryID   
       AND t2.ServiceName='Shoveling'
     )
```

You can achieve this above data by using below Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM @Table1 t1
where ServiceName not in('Shoveling')
```